# MYSQL primary key strategy for microservices architecture

Tags: mysql, microservices

We are currently using auto-generated primary keys and we would like to switch to an approach which is more suitable for microservices-based applications: either we are going to use business defined primary key (a tax code for persons) or global unique identifiers.

- In the past, MySQL had performance issues when using alphanumeric primary keys instead of autoincrement, is it still the case?
- Is it possible, if we go for the UUID approach, to use a strong uuid generator which will guarantee the uuid will be unique even across different servers?

Comment: With auto generated primary keys these are numeric and auto incremented, if you are using some other key which is alpha-numeric then there could be an issue as the contents of the field are examined over a straight numeric match.

Comment: microservices are a very widely adopted architecture pattern which brings lot of benefits compared to monoliths

Comment: Why is centralising primary key generation *more suitable for microservices* ?

Comment: it is not, we are actually thinking about having N databases. But having a unique UUID across N databases makes analytics easier / better

Comment: Using UUIDs as primary keys has significant overhead from an index fragmentation perspective, even if you use a sequential UUID generation routine. This is for SQL Server but I imagine MySQL has similar constraints.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to change the increment step & offset of auto increment to ensure uniqueness over a cloud of MySQL hosts. All instances can have the same increment size, but a different initial offset which will ensure no primary keys clash.

This approach also has the minor advantage that you can tell immediately from the primary column in row of data which database instance created it.

In my.cnf, add:

```
auto-increment-increment = 100
auto-increment-offset = N
```

Where N is between 0 and 99 and unique to each database instance. If you plan for more or less than 100 database instances then you can change the value of 'auto-increment-increment' as well.

With this configuration, a instance with N=1 will generate auto increment values of

```
1,101,201,301,401,501... and so on
```

N=2 will generate

```
2,102,202,302,402,502... and so on
```

Also ensure that that primary key column size also takes into account that increments will now be in steps of 100 and will overflow sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Using a guid is my prepared approach, the guids would be generated by the creator not the database, moreover, I would not recommend using referential integrity in a distributed system's persistence for transactional data as this will reduce the ability to scale out your component.

Given eventual consistency and distribution of code to separate processes, your transactional data has no meaningful state to the outside world, the meaningful business state should be written to a view model data store once it is in a meaningful state (done creating a user, done verifying a user and so on).

Make sense?